# illustrator pencil tool jagged line problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, path

I used pencil tool, but almost lines are jagged.
I checked anti-aliased art work in preference setting,
but it can't solve the problem.

and I will use the picture for web. (700px * 344px)
It is okay in 6400% view, but the lines are jagged in 100% view.

Any idea to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried exporting to SVG?

Answer (score 1):

Your monitor **has** to use pixels to display *anything*. If you really want less pixels to be visible, you need a better monitor with a higher pixel density.

Although they appear jagged on screen, they are smoothed when printed or exported with "Art Optimized" anti-alias settings.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen if you're in **View** > **Pixel Preview** mode (though that is usually **very** obvious) OR in **View** > **Outline** mode Command or Ctrl+Y.